# How to create dynamic router for catalog items

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to work with [Kunstmaan bundles](http://bundles.kunstmaan.be/) for Symfony2 and have one issue. 
Currently I'm trying to create catalog bundle, everything seems okey, but I don't want to create menu item for each product. It would be great to access products dynamicaly by item slug-title in /en/catalog/* menu item. How is it possible?

Comment: Have a look here http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/routing.html. The first example is about your issue.

Answer (score 3):

We are experiencing the same problem ... we are trying to solve this by creating catalog items which are also menu items but have null as parent so that they don't show up in the tree. By doing this you still have the versioning system and everything but it doesn't slow down your tree when you have many catalog items. You can list these catalog items somewhere in an admin list using the AdminListBundle (https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanAdminListBundle)

To link these catalog items to a certain overview page we are using the chainrouter (https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanNodeBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/NodeBundle.md). For now we don't have a clear example of this but maybe this can get you started? We are trying to make using the chainrouter easier, but it's still under construction: https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanNodeBundle/pull/38/files

Answer (score 1):

The fastest/easiest way would to make your product as a page which can be defined as a child for your Catalog. The KunstmaanNodeBundle will take care of the slugs.

In your Catalog class (I assume it extends AbstractPage) override the getPossibleChildTypes method :

```
public function getPossibleChildTypes()
{
    return array (
        array(
            'name' => 'Product',
            'class'=> "Acme\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product"
        )
    );
}
```

This way you can just create products as subpages under your catalog page. Then you just need to get the children of your catalog in the twig template of your catalog page.

The drawback is, is that each product is a page on its own (with versioning) instead of being a simple Entity.